# Equivalent statement of the compactness theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

While studying the compactness theorem, I was asked to prove equivalence of two statements of the theorem. I researched a bit and came across a question on this site that would hopefully answer my question, but the part that was unclear to the original author is unclear to me as well, and the accepted answer gave a rather short explanation, which I struggle to understand. The question: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2727151/376071)

I will rephrase the question myself, starting off with the two statements.

> 1. Let $\Gamma$ be a set of propositional formulas, and let $\phi$ be a formula. If $\Gamma\models \phi$, then there is a finite subset $\Gamma_0\subset\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_0\models\phi$.
> 2. If for each finite $\Gamma_0\subset\Gamma$ we have a model, then for $\Gamma$ we have a model.

After that, the author says

> Now for $2\implies 1$, my book writes the following: Suppose 2. is true. Let $\Gamma$ be a set of propositional formulas, and let $\phi$ be a formula such that $\Gamma\models\phi$. Then there is no model for $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\phi\}$, **and because of our assumption, there exists a finite $\Gamma_0\subset\Gamma$ such that there is no model for $\Gamma_0\cup\{\neg\phi\}$**

The bolded part confuses me. If $\Gamma\cup\{\neg\phi\}$ doesn't have a model, then I can only conclude that it itself must have a subset which doesn't have a model either. I'd really appreciate some help understanding how the bolded claim came to be!

Comment: $\Gamma \vDash \phi$ implies $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \phi \}$ has no model, because otherwise we will have a model $M$ that is a model of both $\lnot \phi$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Now, by contraposition of 2, if $Γ \cup \{ ¬ \phi \}$ has **no** model, then the negation of (every finite $Γ_0 \subset \Gamma$ has a model) holds.

Comment: How to negate "every finite ... has a model" ? There is (at least) one finite ... that has **no** model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The negation I have in mind is "there is at least one finite $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$ that has no model." $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_0 \cup \{ \lnot \phi \}$ are different though, but I could claim that since $\Gamma_0$ doesn't have a model, $\Gamma_0 \cup \{ \lnot \phi \}$ can't have one either, right? This then further implies that $\Gamma_0 \models \phi$, thus proving (1). Am I correct in this argumentation?

Comment: No I don't think I'm right in the assumption above. Because with the contraposition of 2, I'd get $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot \phi \} \models \bot \implies \exists \Gamma_0 (\Gamma_0 \subset (\Gamma \cup \{\lnot \phi \}) \land \Gamma_0 \models \bot$), that is my $\Gamma_0$ wouldn't be a subset of $\Gamma$, as required, but a subset of $\Gamma \cup \{\lnot \phi \}$.

Comment: Ok, $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \phi \}$. Two cases : either (i) $\lnot \phi \notin \Gamma_0$, and thus $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$; or (ii) $\lnot \phi \in \Gamma_0$. Then let $\Gamma_1= \Gamma_0 \setminus \{ \lnot \phi \}$ and we have $\Gamma_1 \subset \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_1 \cup \{ \lnot \phi \}$ has no model.

Comment: Hey. I gave your comment a bit of thought and it all makes perfect sense now. Thank you very much! If you want, you can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it, otherwise I'll summarize the proof myself when I'm home for any future readers.